# Foreach loop php conversion

Tags: php, for-loop

I execute on my main page some php code which includes :

```
foreach ($fbdata->feed->data as $fbpost)
{
    ...
}
```

How can we convert this , into a loop that goes from (i to z)(0 to 10) ?

Comment: Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)?

Comment: @alanlittle I didn't find how to use the " as " in a simple for loop

Comment: You shouldn't be using a foreach loop if you want to define the bounds on which the loop runs. Use a basic for loop.

Comment: @Chad Fisher what I really want is to use the "as" in a simple for loop...

Comment: `foreach ($fbdata->feed->data as $key => $fbpost)` perhaps

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $fbpost = $fbdata->feed->data[$i];
    ...
}
```

or if you like to use the *as*, try using a foreach but slicing the array before using it

```
$fbPosts = array_slice($fbdata->feed->data, 0, 10);
foreach($fbPosts as $fbpost) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . Do you think  $fbdata->feed->data[0] or $fbdata->feed->data[$i] is the right one?

Comment: Yeah you're right, was a typo... `$fbdata->feed->data[$i]` is correct... I fix the answer